# ImportError cannot import name 'ContextVar' when using Werkzeug with FlaskAPI

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I am trying to follow this guide: https://www.imaginarycloud.com/blog/flask-python/ in order to generate documentation for my flask app. After I installed the werkzeug, I started getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jnordling/.local/bin/flask", line 5, in <module>
    from flask.cli import main
  File "/home/jnordling/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .app import Flask as Flask
  File "/home/jnordling/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    from werkzeug.local import ContextVar
ImportError: cannot import name 'ContextVar'
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Install flask: pip install flask
- Create a Basic flask app
- Install flask-restplus: pip install flask-restplus
- Install Werkzeug: pip install Werkzeug
- Create Documentation Endpoint:
- Run App

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick glance through the tutorial, it looks like it might be a package version compatibility issue.

Have you tried upgrading Flask and Werkzeug to the latest versions?

Maybe try:

```
pip install Flask Werkzeug -U
```

Answer (score 0):

It's version incompatibility that's causing the issue. A clean uninstall followed by a fresh install should fix the issue.

```
pip uninstall Flask Werkzeug
pip install Flask Werkzeug
```